# Who robbed the bank?

Tags: puzzle

Three suspects are arrested for a bank robbery.  Suspect $A$ says he did not rob the bank.  Suspect $B$ says he did not rob the bank.  Suspect $C$ says suspect $B$ did not rob the bank.

If $A$ is telling the truth, then that means $B$ and $C$ are lying, which means that $B$ robbed the bank.

Is this correct?

EDIT: Sorry for not including this, the restriction is only one is telling the truth.

Comment: If $A$ is telling the truth exists the posibility of $B$ and $C$ don't lie.

Comment: Why must you assume that B and C are lying if A is telling the truth?

Comment: Only one is telling the truth.  I edited my question to add it.  Sorry.

Comment: Then yes, if A don't lie then $B$ rob the bank.

Comment: If A robbed the bank, how many are telling the truth. If B was the robber? If C was the robber?

Comment: Assume C is telling the truth. The B did not rob the bank. But B is lying so he did rob the bank. This is a contradiction so C must be lying. This implies that B robbed the bank so B is lying and A is telling the truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the assumption that only one suspect is telling the truth, the solution can be established in one fell swoop:  If B is telling the truth, then C is also telling the truth; this would violate the assumption, so B must be lying, and hence he is the robber.

You can, of course, consider all the other possibilities as well and rule them all out, but you don't need to.

Comment: Technically, one should also verify that when when B is lying, exactly one of A and C is telling the truth. (Puzzles don't have to be logically consistent: it could very well be the case that the puzzle is posed to have no solutions...)

Answer (score 1):

Assume A is telling the truth, then B and C must be lying then, B must rob the bank, but as B is lying, he must have robbed the bank, C is lying so B has robbed the bank, So A is not lying,  he's telling the truth.

Assume B is telling the truth then A and C are lying, then B must rob the bank according to C, contradiction.

Assume C is telling the truth so B hasn't robbed the bank, B is lying this means he has robbed, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the only logical choice.